# How to animate listview item on-press instead of on-release?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-animation

I want to animate my listview items on pressing. Currently i am doing it by adding animation in OnItemClick Listener , but the problem is the animation is not getting started on pressing the item, instead it starts on releasing it. As another activity opens on clicking the item, the animation becomes insigniicant

Here is my OnItemClick method:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        Animation a= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanimation);
        view.startAnimation(a);
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));
    }
```

Comment: You can use onTouch or GestureListener for your listview